# How can I pass some values to my implementation of java.io.FileFilter?

Tags: java, java-7

I implemented `java.io.FileFilter` in this way:

```java
//get a list of files that:
    // aren't directories
    // have lastmodified times over X seconds in the past.
//And only get first Y files, even if there are more present.
private File[] getInputFiles(String inputDirectory) {
    return new File(inputDirectory).listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        int counter = 2; //TODO parameterize as Y

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            counter--;
            return !pathname.isDirectory()
                && pathname.lastModified() < 
                    System.currentTimeMillis() - 30 * 1000 //TODO parameterize as X
                && counter >= -1;

        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, there are magic numbers in my code.  I want to replace them with parameters.

I tried `new FileFilter(int X, int Y) {...}`, but that's a compile-time error.

Note: Java 7.  (I think some Java 8 features could help here, right?  Unfortunately, this should be Java 7.)

Comment: Simply declare some local or class constant variables and use them in the anonymous class body.

Comment: ... or change the anonymous class into a normal one to pass the counter as ctor argument.

Comment: May I ask of what use the `counter`is? At first I thought you want to restrict the number of found files to 2 - but this wouldn't be the case e.g. if the first 2 entries are directories - than the array will be empty.

Comment: OK, I've just found the comment at the beginnig of your method (maybe this will not work as intended)...

Comment: @tomse, you found a bug! Thank you.

Comment: @Davis Broda, yep, that's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Java 7+, don't bother with `File`. Use java.nio.file.

And what you want is a `DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>`. It has pretty much the same signature as a `FileFilter`, with the advantage that the method you will use to fetch entries from a directory (`Files.newDirectoryStream()`) will actually return a *lazily loaded iterator of directory entries* where `File` will load all the entries.

```
public final class MyFilter
    implements DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>
{
    // Now minus 30 seconds
    private final FileTime timestamp
        = FileTime.fromMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - 30_000);
    private int counter;

    public MyFilter(final int initialCounter)
    {
        counter = initialCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(final Path entry)
    {
        counter--;

        if (!Files.isRegularFile(entry))
            return false;
        if (Files.getLastModifiedTime(entry).compareTo(timestamp) >= 0)
            return false;

        return counter > 0;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
private List<Path> getInputFiles(final String baseDir, final int counter)
{
    final Path path = Paths.get(baseDir);
    final List<Path> result = new ArrayList<>();
    final DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter
        = new MyFilter(counter);

    try (
        final DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path, filter);
    ) {
        for (final Path entry: stream)
            result.add(entry);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, using java.nio.file is vastly preferable.  By the way, the DirectoryStream should be (auto)closed, and IOException should be declared in the method signature (or caught).  I'm guessing you know all that, but people copying the answer verbatim might not.

Comment: @VGR excellent point; fixed

Comment: fge and @VGR, this answer is what I'll use.  The question I originally asked was a duplicate as marked above..  This answer answers the question I *should* have asked!

Comment: May I ask why `final` is used all over?

Comment: @daveloyall to make it clear that I won't change the value of variables once they are initialized; it's a coding style habit, which some people enforce and some people frown upon...